# ASP.NET enable CORS for comma-separated list of methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to enable cors in my ASP.NET Web API. **I am using WebApiConfig.cs (not attributes in controller) to keep configuration for origins in my Web.config file**. WebApiConfig.cs looks like this:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        //CORS settings
        string allowedOrigins = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowedOrigins"].ToString();
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(allowedOrigins, "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**3rd parameter of EnableCorsAttribute() constructor is a "Comma-separated list of methods that are supported by the resource."**

I have a controller with public methods but I want to allow only certain methods to be available from another domain.

**I tried to list them by name:**

```
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(allowedOrigins, "*", "SaveChatResult,MapSessionToInteraction");
```

**I tried to list them by [Route] attribute:**

```
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(allowedOrigins, "*", "api/Widget/SaveChatResult,api/Widget/MapSessionToInteraction");
```

But only "*" works for all. I can not control it by methods. **How to put this 3rd string method parameter to enable cors only for desired methods in controller?**

Comment: The `methods` parameter refers to a comma separated list of **_HTTP_** methods (i.e. `"GET,POST,PUT"`), not routes and not the names of controller methods. If you want to selectively enable CORS, you cannot do it that way. See [Microsoft's documentation for details on enabling CORS with various granularities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#scope-rules-for-enablecors).

Comment: Ok... so I need to use attribute:
[EnableCors(origins: allowedOrigins, headers: "*", methods: "*")]
but it must be const. Any idea how to read it from configuration? :D

Comment: There are various ways you could read that from configuration, I'm not saying that it has to be applied at the attribute level, but that's the easiest. If you can add an example of some of your config, how that config indicates which controllers and methods it applies to, that would help.

Comment: One thing to look at, [further down in that tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#custom-cors-policy-providers), is implementing a CORS policy provider which can compute the rules on demand, (so no `const` attribute's args restriction). The provider can be registered for invocation on each request and can determine a CORS policy based on that request's properties such as target route.